# How can I show Calendar Type Data in FreeMarker

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

I spent lots of time on this, it made me crazy.

In Java controller,var mycalendar is Calendar Type.Put it into model

```
model.addAttribute("mycalendar", mycalendar);
```

In Freemarker template:

```
${pp}
```

Error like this:

```
java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1507864967342,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Shanghai",offset=28800000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=19,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=9,WEEK_OF_YEAR=41,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=13,DAY_OF_YEAR=286,DAY_OF_WEEK=6,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=0,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=11,MINUTE=22,SECOND=47,MILLISECOND=342,ZONE_OFFSET=28800000,DST_OFFSET=0]
```

How can I show this Calendar type correctly like 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to transform your `java.util.Calendar` into a `java.util.Date`, and then apply a freemarker builtin to format it:

```
${pp.time?string["yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"]}
```

Comment: For later readers: Note that you can also write `${pp.time?datetime}`, in which case it will be formatted according the `datetime_format` configuration setting. (`?datetime` is needed here as from a bare `java.util.Date` it's impossible to tell reliably if it meant to be date-only, time-only or a date-time value.)